# Why does my AutoHotKey script not send the checkbox when pressing Enter/NumpadEnter -- only when clicking the button?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I have this code:

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance Off

Gui, New, -MinimizeBox, % "Test"
Gui, Add, Edit, vUserInput w300
Gui, Add, Checkbox, vMyCheckbox1, % "Ceckbox one"
Gui, Add, Checkbox, vMyCheckbox2, % "Checkbox two"
Gui, Add, Button, gOkButtonPress w50 h25 x80, % "OK"
Gui, Show, Center
return

Enter::
Gosub, OkButtonPress

NumpadEnter::
Gosub, OkButtonPress

OkButtonPress:
    Gui, Submit
    MsgBox, Meow! %MyCheckbox2%
    ExitApp
return
```

If I run it and click the "OK" button, it pops up a GUI box saying "Meow! 0" or "Meow! 1" depending on if the second checkbox is checked or unchecked. This is how I want it to be.

However, if I press `Enter` or `NumpadEnter`, it only goes "Meow!" with no "0" or "1"; the checkbox value is ignored.

How is this possible? I've cursed over this for several hours yesterday and today, helplessly trying to read the manual and searching but finding nothing.

I find AutoHotKey to be very strange in general.

(I've also tried adding `return` after each of those `Gosub`s, and many other things.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very weird thing indeed.
I'd say it's my bad for using `Gui, New` in the other answer I wrote for you.

`Gui, New` creates a new gui, and sets it as the default gui, just like any other method of creating a gui would. **But** it only sets it as the default gui for the current thread.
So, when you run a hotkey, you're in a hotkey thread.
And in that thread it's not the default gui, instead a gui named `1` is the default gui.
So the call to `Gui, Submit` tries to refer to the gui `1`, but it doesn't exist.

You'd fix this by naming your gui, and then referring to the gui by its name:

```
Gui, MyCoolGui:New, -MinimizeBox, % "Test" ;name the gui
Gui, Add, Edit, vUserInput w300
Gui, Add, Checkbox, vMyCheckbox1, % "Ceckbox one"
Gui, Add, Checkbox, vMyCheckbox2, % "Checkbox two"
Gui, Add, Button, gOkButtonPress w50 h25 x80, % "OK"
Gui, Show, Center
;each of the gui commands couldve been explicitly specified
;to operate on the named gui "MyCoolGui" like MyCoolGui:Add, MyCoolGui:Show
;but it's redundant
return

Enter::         ;no need to gosub, or goto, 
NumpadEnter::   ;just stack the hotkeys and labels
OkButtonPress:  ;like this
    Gui, MyCoolGui:Submit   ;refer to our named gui
    MsgBox, % "Meow! " MyCheckbox2
    ExitApp
return
```

Alternatively you could not use `Gui, New`, and you could do this:

```
Gui, -MinimizeBox
Gui, Add, Edit, vUserInput w300
Gui, Add, Checkbox, vMyCheckbox1, % "Ceckbox one"
Gui, Add, Checkbox, vMyCheckbox2, % "Checkbox two"
Gui, Add, Button, gOkButtonPress w50 h25 x80, % "OK"
Gui, Show, Center, % "Test" ;give a title on the show command
return

Enter::         
NumpadEnter::   
OkButtonPress:  
    Gui, Submit 
    MsgBox, % "Meow! " MyCheckbox2
    ExitApp
return
```

The [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#New) for `Gui, New` describes some of the ups and downs for for using either of these two methods.
But if you're just sticking to one single gui, instead of having multiple ones, maybe I would for simplicity's sake recommend not using `Gui, New` so you won't have to worry about naming your gui.