# creating a window using AHK that is semi transparent

Tags: autohotkey

Using AutoHotkey, I am trying to create a window which is semi transparent.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
WinTitle := "mywin"
Gui, New, , %WinTitle%
Gui, Color, 0x000000,
WinSet, Transparent, 150, %WinTitle%          ; THIS NEEDS FIXING?
w := A_ScreenWidth/4
h := A_ScreenHeight/4
Gui, Show, x100 y100 w%w% h%h%
```

This does create a black window, but it is not semi transparent.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window doesn't exist before you show it.
So, you have to set the transparency after you show the window.

```
Gui, +hwnd_hwnd
Gui, Color, 0x000000

w := A_ScreenWidth / 4
h := A_ScreenHeight / 4
Gui, Show, % "x100 y100 w" w " h" h

WinSet, Transparent, 150, % "ahk_id " _hwnd
```

Misc improvements:

- Not using `Gui, New`.
  (It's fine to use, but be sure to know what you're using it for, and how to use it, to avoid tricky problems such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749806/why-does-my-autohotkey-script-not-send-the-checkbox-when-pressing-enter-numpaden/64750451) one)
- Refer to the window using hwnd.
  Hwnd can be retrieved via e.g `+hwnd`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#GuiHwndOutputVar)</sup> option.
- Ditched the legacy syntax in favor of the modern expression syntax.