# Can't Hide And Show GUI

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

I am practicing my AutoHotkey skills and seem to have run into a bit of a problem.

I am specifically trying to play around and learn how to create an make a GUI, but now am trying to make a way to show and hide a GUI window.
The code I have so far is:

```
; redundant variables for clarity
showConfig := true
hotkeyNew1 := ""
hotkeyNew2 := ""

; prompt for the hotkeys
Gui, New, , Config
Gui, Add, Text, x10 y10, Enter a hotkey for MsgBox1
Gui, Add, Hotkey, x+0 vhotkeyNew1, %vhotkeyNew1%
Gui, Add, Text, x10 y+0, Enter a hotkey for MsgBox2
Gui, Add, Hotkey, x+0 vhotkeyNew2, %vhotkeyNew2%
Gui, Add, Button, x10 y+0 w100 gSendHotkeys, Set Hotkeys
Gui, Show, hide w200 h100 Center, Config ; I assume this initializes the GUI? Either way, it doesn't seem to change anything if I omit it

!+s::
/*
; Note that this was my first attempt, but it yeilded a blank GUI
Gui, Show, % (showConfig ? "" : "hide") . " w200 h100", Config
*/
; This was my second attempt, also yielding a blank GUI
if (showConfig) {
    Gui, Config:Show, w200 h100 Center, Config
} else {
    Gui, Config:Hide
}
showConfig := !showConfig
return


SendHotkeys:
Hotkey, %hotkeyNew1%, hotkey1
Hotkey, %hotkeyNew2%, hotkey2
return

hotkey1:
MsgBox, Hotkey1
return

hotkey2:
MsgBox, Hotkey2
return

#+e:: ExitApp
```

Is there a way to hide and unhide a GUI with a hotkey? I can't seem to get it to work. I am writing the script and then compiling it, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You've accidentally ran into quite a weird problem here.
It's something I've wrote an answer for earlier, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64750451/3813732

That should solve your problem, let me know if you have any problems.

Other than that, I'd like to say your approach of calling `Show` and `Hide` on a named gui would've worked, but you actually never named your gui.
To name your gui, your first gui code line should've been:
`Gui, Config:New, , Config`

Also, you're redundantly re-specifying information in gui commands, such as the gui's title. It's all stored once you specify it once, no need to specify it multiple times.